# Symfony3 - rendering matrix of checkboxes

Tags: symfony

I need to create 3 types of accommodation: a *hotel*, a *house* and a *room*. Each one of them should optionally include following services: *breakfast*, *TV* and *towels*. The idea is to create a matrix of checkboxes and store it in the database in a single field as a JSON string. The matrix should look like this:

[image]

I have a problem implementing this idea with Formbuilder. I've already addressed the Symfony documentation to no avail. The code I have right now looks like this:

```
     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $checkboxes = [
            'Hotel' => 'hotel', 'House' => 'house', 'Room' => 'room'
        ];

        $builder
            ->add('accommodations', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => $checkboxes,
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ));
    }
```

Comment: The code looks like this... And what's the problem?

Comment: The issue is that "I have a problem implementing this idea with Formbuilder". The code provided is nowhere near solving this problem, I don't even know if I am on the right path...

Comment: You have to [customize the display](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html), which is going to be in the Twig file.

Comment: A matrix-like form selection that transforms data to a JSON string sounds like an excellent candidate for a custom form type as well as data transformer.

Comment: @JasonRoman could you please elaborate on the subject?

Comment: Check the following links: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html .  Basically if you're having a unique type like that, you could create a custom type and pass it the rows/columns you need, and you could create the Twig template to display that.  Then the DataTransformer would take everything you submit and automatically convert it to JSON.